# Rambam on Sacrifices

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam, korban

I seem to recall hearing that the Rambam stated somewhere that animal sacrifices were not necessary from G-d's point of view, but that He decided to institute them because of what the Israelites were used to. Anyone know which text this is or if I've miss attributed it?

Comment: See the comments to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52743/5323

Comment: @Shokhet [These comments](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19564220#19564220) about the Rambam's view (moved to chat) are relevant.

Comment: @Fred Oh, I didn't even see those. I was referring to the ones that are *currently* under the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The Rambam writes as much in [Moreh Nevochim 3:32](http://www.daat.ac.il/DAAT/mahshevt/more/c11-2.htm#2). It is slightly expanded upon in [3:46](http://www.daat.ac.il/DAAT/mahshevt/more/c15-2.htm#1).

As an aside, it should be considered with the Rambam at the end of Hilchos Me'ila, which many understand to be a contradiction to that. (For a brief discussion of this point, see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6865/maimonides-and-sacrifices-as-g-ds-concession-to-mankind/37433#37433), although it's far from a complete treatment of the issue.)