# Did Hevel slaughter his sacrifice?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, korban, slaughter-shochet-shecht

Genesis 4:4 states that Hevel offered an animal sacrifice. I recall learning that Kayin attacked Hevel with several blows because he did not know where/how to kill. My question is, did Hevel slaughter his offering, and if so with what implement? (Genesis 4:22 indicates that sharpened metal instruments were fashioned after Hevel's death).

Comment: See Ibn Ezra there.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10994/759

Answer (score 6):

[Radak](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34563&st=&pgnum=34&hilite=) says that Hevel left his Korban tied up, and was awaiting for a fire to come down from heaven to devour it.

> כמדומה לי שלא שחט הקרבן אלא הניחו חי קשור באותו מקום הקבוע לו כדי שירד
>   עליו אש מן השמים לאכלו

Answer (score 3):

In [Bereishis Rabbah 22:5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14385&st=&pgnum=54&hilite=) R. Yosi bar Hanina says that Hevel offered the sacrifice without having been flayed or cut up.

> והכתיב ו**הבל** הביא גם הוא מבכורות צאנו ומחלביהן, דבר שחלבו קרב. מה עבד
>   ליה לר' יוסי? עביד ליה, מן שמניהון. אתיב ר' אלעזר לרבי יוסי: והא כתיב
>   (שמות כד): וישלח את נערי בני ישראל, ויעלו עולות ויזבחו זבחים שלמים לה'
>   פרים. מה עביד ליה ר' יוסי בר חנינא? **שלמים, בלא הפשט וניתוח**

Comment: I don't see anything in that quote which refers to Hevel. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is the relevant part from a debate between R. Yosi and and R. Eleazar which starts at והבל הביא גם הוא מבכורות צאנו ומחלביהן there. Should I add this too to the answer?

Comment: You have plenty of character space available. I think adding enough of the quote to clarify what's going on and a relevant translation would definitely improve your post.

Comment: I'll add that to clarify then.

Comment: How do we see it was not killed?

Comment: Are you sure it's שְׁלֵמִים?  I think שְׁלָמֵים makes more sense.