# Penalty for eating meat prior to it being permitted

Tags: animals, meat, parashat-noach

Prior to the flood, mankind was not allowed to eat meat (Sanhedrin 59b, various other sources and interpretations [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3660/eating-meat-what-changed)). During this time, was there a penalty for killing and eating an animal, just as there is a penalty for killing a human being? [Sforno seems to suggest otherwise](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.9.6?lang=bi&with=Sforno&lang2=he), but from context it seems he may only be referring to the post-flood era.

Comment: Was there really a penalty for killing a human being (or any other sins, for that matter) prior to the flood? There is one recorded case of murder in the Torah, and the murderer seemed to 'get away with it', in a sense (i.e. wasn't executed for his crime).

Comment: @PopularIsn'tRight I think the prohibition was just on killing animals; that is, they could have eaten an animal that died naturally