# Why don't humans have the best version of organs?

Tags: science, creation, adam, biology

Scientifically speaking, a better version of an organ could be found in many animals (besides the human brain, maybe). IIRC, octopuses have better eyes, birds have a more efficient cardiovascular system, dogs have better olfactory senses, primates have stronger muscles, cats - better hearing, lizards have far better regenerative abilities, snakes have thermo-sensing, bats - echolocation, sharks - some anti-cancer antigens and ever-regenerating teeth, and much more. (*Please don't argue on those details, the list is exemplary, not exhaustive*)

If so, I understand that God intentionally prevented humans from having "better parts", which were implemented in lower species, so **Adam was biologically imperfect**, so to speak.

Why humans don't have the best version of organs and systems?

Comment: Maybe our biological imperfections are a clear mashul for the fact that we are likewise spiritually imperfect and the mission in life is to work on ourselves to grow in that respect.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Tazria.5.1?lang=he

Comment: Great question. Just as a random example, if humans had the olfactory senses that dogs do, we would likely be prohibited from ever reciting the shema or praying shimonei esrei in an inhabited area (since we would be able to perceive bad smells from very far away).

Comment: Is the adjective best subjective in this case?

Comment: who says they aren't the best? they are the best for humans because they're human organs

Comment: "best" is objective. If humans had the biggest, strongest hearts and organs then you're basically a dinosaur. I mean there's no limit...

Comment: Why would they? I don't understand the premise of the question.

Answer (score 6):

Humans have the perfect version of organs and systems needed to complete their mission on earth.

Each person and their mission.

In the rare case where you need an improved version - you're a detective who could use great  olfactory senses - you train a canine to help you.

When you need to travel great distance, you use the relevant animal for the ride.

As [Josh K](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/16622/josh-k) commented, having all your senses turbo-charged would cause endless issues; sensory overload, anybody?

So Adam was biologically perfect, for his mission. Simply because your food processor can't make phone calls and your phone cannot squeeze OJ, doesn't mean they aren't perfect.

Comment: I understand your "שמח בחלקו" attitude, but we don't call it "perfect" we call it "suitable". And there's a huge difference. You don't refer to any sources. So it doesn't count as a real answer. I'm greatly disappointed.

Comment: The ability to train an animal or to invent technology to enhance an existing sense or make a new one is a special gift from God anyway

Comment: This is hindsight. Drawing the bullseye around the arrow... or is that the point?

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that man's organs were originally the best version but were dimished after the chait of Aitz Hadaas?

As [Chagigah 12a](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.12a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says Adam was diminished:

> Rav Yehuda said that Rav said: The size of Adam the first man was from one end of the world to the other, as it is stated: “Since the day that God created man upon the earth, and from one end of the heavens to the other,” which indicates that he spanned the entire length of the world. Once he sinned, the Holy One, Blessed be He, placed His hand upon him and diminished him, as it states: “And laid Your hand upon me.”

Before the sin there was no death or disease hence man's regenerative abilities would not have the same relevance.
Another question that perhaps needs to be asked as well as the original question is would the "superior" organs of animals still be the same had Adam not sinned either? 
We already know that at least the snake changed from a walking creature to one that walks on its belly (Genesis 3:14). Was it only necessary for Hashem to put that thermo-sensing ability in them at a later point (after the sin) to cope with the post chait world? 
Also animals would not eat each other before the sin.

see: https://www.sefaria.org/Or_HaChaim_on_Genesis.1.30.1?lang=bi

Would this indicate a need for further changes in the organs of more animals as well or would their organs have remained the same with or without the sin taking place?

Also Someone posted a Midrash Agadah saying animals were also supposed to live forever before the sin: [Eating Meat: What Changed?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3660/eating-meat-what-changed)

Comment: The biggest - yes, but how come "the best"? Anyway, why after diminishing, would God impair his organs?

Comment: tried to address the question more.

Answer (score 1):

> Adam was biologically imperfect.

And that's correct:

**Deuteronomy 32**

> 46 And he said to them, "Set your hearts to all of the words which I bear witness for you this day, so that you may command your children to observe to do all the words of this Torah.
>
> 47 For it is not an empty thing for you, **for it is your life, and through this thing, you will lengthen your days** upon the land to which you are crossing over the Jordan, to possess it."

Id est, God created Adam with plan in mind that he should be neither perfect nor inherently guided, he needs a helper to walk in the right way.

Naturally speaking, it can be considered that the human weakness is actually his strength, because our ancestors main target and question was:

> **How can I improve the situation?**

This in fact is still our concern, we always change what's present, and what we had yesterday became obsolete, and what is waiting for us tomorrow is our goal to achieve, yet not satisfied.

Why all the progress? .... Because that was the main point for creating mankind weak:

> Genesis 17:1 And Abram was ninety-nine years old, and God appeared to Abram, and He said to him, "I am the Almighty God; **walk before Me and be perfect."**

Although I'm a Gentile, the perfect human is not with the perfect organs, but the one who follows God's path, and we can still see that His planning for creating all beings with weak points helped mankind with positive results, for example:

1. It improved our understanding of anatomy, hence healthcare.
2. Emphasized excavating nature for resources and life needs.
3. More effort to reinnovate our sheltering systems.
4. Helped us to establish citizenship, a community is what any human needs.
5. Better solutions for daily life problems like transportation, computation, data collecting, education systems, engineering, communication, etc...

All of these achievements happened for a reason, that we seek to improve based on what God left us to deal with, that's what He taught Adam when he sinned, that Adam must find a solution to progress.

It will also make sense if you flipped the case by purposing if God created Adam perfect without weakness, and this is where God's wisdom explains itself:

> Numbers 23:19 God is not a man that He should lie, nor is He a mortal that He should relent. Would He say and not do, speak and not fulfill?

Comment: Thank you, well written. An inspiring idea. I didn't mean "imperfect" in a sense of complete perfection, I meant that since God already had better parts, why didn't he use them to create a *biologically better* human, humans with better functioning bodies.