# Where does R. Achay Gaon say it's a mitzva to eat meat?

Tags: mitzvah, eating, meat, parashat-reeh, geonim

Deuteronomy 12:20, with Rabbi Kaplan's translation:

> When God expands your borders as He promised you, and your natural desire to eat meat asserts itself, so that you say, 'I wish to eat meat,' you may eat as much meat as you wish.

That last "you may eat" is a translation of "תֹּאכַל", which can also be translated "you shall eat". Someone told me recently that [*Rav Achay Gaon*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achai_Gaon) says that this is one of the 613 *mitzvos* (commands): if someone wants to eat meat, he fulfills a *mitzva* by doing so.
I don't see it [in the *Sh'iltos* ad loc.](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/sheiltot/sheiltot10.pdf); does anyone have a citation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somebody probably meant R. Saadya Gaon - see [R. Yerucham Perlow's commentary (aseh 95)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Commentary_on_Sefer_Hamitzvot_of_Rasag%2C_Positive_Commandments.95) who notes that the Rasag counts as a mitzvah 
"רחב גבוליך והתאוית תדשנה טובי ותשבע". R. Yerucham Perlow explains that this refers to the obligation not to deny oneself the pleasures of this world:

> כוונת רבינו הגאון ז"ל במצוה זו צ"ע טובא. ולפי המבואר 
>    כוונתו בזה לקרא דפרשת ראה דכתיב כי ירחיב ה"א את גבלך ואמרת אוכלה בשר כי תאוה נפשך לאכל בשר בכל אות נפשך תאכל בשר. אבל אינו מובן לכאורה כלל איזו מצוה יש בזה...וגם במנין האזהרות אשר על סדר עשרת הדברות מנה רבינו הגאון ז"ל עשה זו (בדבור לא תחמוד). שכתב שם וז"ל אלקים ינקי בדשן בשר התאוה עכ"ל עיי"ש. וכן באזהרות הר"א הזקן ז"ל מנה עשה זו במספר העשין. וז"ל חשק בשר תאוה כי ירחיב לך פתר. אמר ה' אכול והותר עכ"ל. וכן באזהרות אתה הנחלת מנה עשה זו. שכתב זביחת בשר לאכול בתאוה עיי"ש... ולכן נראה לי יותר דכוונת רבינו הגאון ז"ל וסייעתו בזה דס"ל דלפום פשטי' דקרא דכי ירחיב ה"א את גבולך וגו' היא מצוה חיובית. **שאם הרחיב השם גבולו ותאוה נפשו לאכול בשר חייב הוא לאכול**. וזהו שמסיים הכתוב בכל אות נפשך תאכל בשר. שהוא לשון ציווי ככל המצות שבתורה. ולאו דוקא בשר אלא כל דבר כיו"ב בכלל המצוה. ומדנקט קרא בשר ס"ל לר"י שבא הכתוב להתיר להם בשר תאוה. שמתחילה נאסר להם. אבל פשטי' דקרא הוא מצות עשה גמורה כדכתיבנא. והיינו דאמרינן בירושלמי (סוף קידושין) רבי חזקי' רבי כהן בשם רב עתיד אדם ליתן דין וחשבון על כל שראתה עינו ולא אכל. רבי לעזר חשש להדא שמועתא ומצמית ליה פריטין ואכיל בהון מכל מילה חדא בשתא עיי"ש.

Comment: Many thanks. Any idea who "הר״א הזקן" is?

Comment: . . . ah, it seems to be https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%94%D7%96%D7%A7%D7%9F. Not _R' Achay_, then