# Are the animals killed for tefillin killed humanely?

Tags: tefilin, tzaar-baalei-chayyim

Are the cows used to make leather for Tefillin killed humanely? I don't want to pray with something bound to me when that something was made from an inhumanely killed animal.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34811/leather-and-vegetarianism-according-to-rav-kook

Comment: I believe they are killed humanely, but I can't prove it to you since I don't know for certain. I've edited your question for the spelling, if I've done anything you don't like you can [edit] yourself to fix it.

Comment: I've closed this question because it doesn't specify a standard for humaneness.

Comment: @mordcah. I think you raise an excellent question. This was discussed at the following web site: http://www.jewishjournal.com/socialjusticerav/item/praying_with_compassion_time_for_vegan_tefillin_20120624/

Comment: We can't judge "humane" as that's not an objective standard, but if you were to [edit] this to ask instead how the cows are killed, that would be answerable and then you could evaluate the humanity of that yourself. (*Edit: but, I later discovered, it would be a duplicate.  I've reclosed this as a dupe.*)

Comment: There are no requirements for the leather other than its coming from a kosher mammal. The cow could have been lethally injected or flayed alive. You'd have to contact your local Tefillin Manufacturer to see what he uses.

Comment: @MonicaCellio if it were so edited, I don't think it'd be a duplicate: the other question asks the _halacha_ (how can they be killed?) whereas this would ask the facts (how are they killed?). DoubleAA says one would need to ask a manufacturer the latter, but there may actually be a standard operating procedure.

Comment: @msh210 that's a good point, and now that you point it out I agree that that wouldn't be a dupe.